# How to extract link from html file and save to a text file php?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, extract

I have link like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I want only 2 and 3 write to text file using php.Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks for help me:)

Comment: Those aren't links.. do you want to extract the line items content? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php and `file_put_contents`.

Comment: if you want to use particular 2 and 3 <li> tag. you can give them event id.

Comment: no I suppose those numbers are link just like <ul><li><a href="#"></li></ul>

Comment: Look at the linked thread it should show you how you can parse HTML/XML. Your question is unclear as your comment differs from your questions comment.

Comment: I REALLY DONT UNDERSTAND

Comment: Don't understand the content on the link provided?